# Showing custom post user wise with different color in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am using **ACF**(advance custom field) and **custom post type** plugin to create my own custom post type.

I have successfully created custom post type with custom field. [no problem here]

Then i have display all custom posts to users(front end user) after login. [no problem here].

if front end user(after login) like particular custom post, he/she will fill-up free subscription form against  particular  custom post and submit it.

Now i want to display all custom posts to users but if user already subscribed for particular post then i want to show it with different color. any solution for this?

Comment: Does subscriptions form adds any user meta fields which has the custom post type name? If so then pls update your question with that.

Comment: No subscription form does not contain any user meta field

Comment: Then how will Admin know that a user X has subscribe to a post type Y?

Comment: Yes that what i want to do, so i can come to know which user like which post and then i can display accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user submits the subscription form, save the current post id in users meta data using some custom meta key(subscribed_posts)

```
<?php 
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'subscribed_posts', $post_id);
//$post_id is the id of post user subscribes to.
?>
```

Now while displaying the post in frontend, just check for the post id and use some specific class to display in different color(write css for that class in your style.css, i've used the class green for subscribed and grey for not subscribed posts.)

```
<?php 
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'fields'        =>'ids'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );//Query for all post that you want to display
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

$subscribed_posts = get_user_meta($user_id);//Get current user id and fetch all subscribed posts.

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
    <div class="default <?php echo in_array(get_the_ID(),$subscribed_posts)?'green':'gray'?>">
        /*Your post content for every post goes here*/
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

Would have been more specific if you had showed the specific codes and html

Comment: Hello do you know any free form plugin that will help me to create dynamic    subscription form and change its fields any time?

Comment: i usually have custom coded subscriptions without plugins. Not that i remmber.

Comment: If i will use any plugin then where i have to write above code?

Comment: The first part (to add the post id in user meta) will be done right after user subscribes( usually plugins provide hooks for such events)

Depends on plugin and hooks provided and data availiable for given hook, but if you have the hook and required data(user id and post id) you can simply add a hook in your function.php file to add the meta.

The part to change color will go into your template file which loads the posts currently.

Comment: how will Admin know that a user ABC has subscribe to a post type XYZ?